# My target SDK version is 26 but when I upload my apk on playstore, app supports only SDK ranging 16 to 19

Tags: android, google-play, static-libraries, android-min-sdk, target-sdk

My projects Gradle file looks like this as given below.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.myappspackagename"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 8
    versionName "1.7"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }

}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
}
```

Now when I test my app on my mobile devices (Samsung Neo [4.2] and Samsung A7 [7.0]) + emulators (different android versions) my app works as per my imagination and how it should work!

I have used few 3rd party libraries.

Now, the problem is when I upload my app on google play store, it only supports versions ranging from 4.1-4.4 (SDK 16-19) only.

What is the probllem going?

Please point me, what have I done wrong?

**EDIT-1:**

Have a look on my Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26"
    tools:overrideLibrary="quatja.com.vorolay" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: show the menifest.xml?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar please have a look on updated data.

Comment: have you checked the quatja.com.vorolay library versions?

Comment: Yes it supports upto SDK 24 @AniruddhParihar

Comment: have a look on https://github.com/Quatja/Vorolay/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: i mean, this library also have android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26"?

Comment: That is because I had errors as per this question, I tried doing this too but it didn't help. Is it because some of the 3rd party libraries supports 16 to 19 SDK? If yes, how can I come to know which library focuses on those SDKs?

Comment: me also thinking about it, normally according to android features if its working in minimum version so it will  also work for max version, but if your library have some limitation then you can't do anything.

Comment: What are the 3rd party libraries you are using?  It's possible one of them has set `maxSdkVersion` to 19.

Comment: So, there is no possible solution? @AniruddhParihar

Comment: @alzee I am using 15+ 3rd party libraries, but I don't know how to find which is having maxSdk set as 19. Is there any way I can find out and then I will remove that library!

Comment: check all library's build.gradle file and change them.

Comment: It should say in the documentation.  Read the readme, errata, release notes, and other such things carefully for each of the libs.  You can also search through all the libs for that string with find/grep or something.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar well I am not sure whether I can edit or not, let me check. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @alzee well, that's the only way I can proceed. Let me proceed with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this issue.
Go to:
Files > Project Structure...

In the window that opens select "app" under modules.
Then pick the tab flavors and set the "Target sdk Version" as 26 or more.